# Post deleted by me then moderator, now I can't edit?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I deleted a post, but the comments still remained. The asker suggested I put one of my comments as the answer, but when I tried to edit it it said you couldn't edit deleted posts. I tried to undelete it, but it said I couldn't because a moderator had deleted it. I can only post more answers (necause of the auto-ban) if I improve upon my existing ones, and the moderators are making this impossible because they keep deleting things.

Comment: It would help if you provided links to the question you're referring to.

Answer (score 4):

Your [original answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/91266/1) was deleted because it wasn't an answer to the question asked. I also felt that it was close to the borderline in terms of coming across as somewhat racist, although I'm assuming that wasn't your intention.

Now that you've edited it into something more suitable (e.g. now that it's actually an answer to the question asked), I've undeleted it for you.

Comment: yeah, i understood the problem with it so I deleted it, thanks for your help :)